# Setting Transperancy To iFrame Inside Modal Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am showing a pdf in the background and a Popup over the top which contains an iFrame I want to set the transparency to the popup.
It works perfectly in Chrome browser and the rest of the browser it doesn't work :( Here is the Fiddler Link : [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kBqqF/8/)

Please Tell Me What should i do to work in all the browsers.

[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

With a little javascript and CSS this should be no biggie, though the iframe will need to be wrapped in a div, or something of the matter:

```
<div id="iframeContainer">
    <iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
// Set the css opacity of the div NOT the iframe:
iframeContainer.style.opacity = 0.5; // the closer to 1 the less transparent
iframeContainer.style.MozOpacity=0.5; // the closer to 1 the less transparent
iframeContainer.style.filters.alpha.opacity=50; // the closer to 100 the less transparent
```

Comment: As i said in my post the transparency works in Chrome but its not working on IE