# Convert PDF file to TIFF file on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is There any Possibility to Convert the PDF TO TIFF On the Fly in Asp.Net and View the Same on the WebForm.

If Yes Is There Any 3rd Party DLL or Open Source DLL for Accomplishing the Same ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to convert pdf files to tiff files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500/best-way-to-convert-pdf-files-to-tiff-files)

Comment: If the purpose of the conversion is to display the document as a set of images in the browser, why do you want to convert to TIFF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically create a TIF from a PDF in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116718/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-tif-from-a-pdf-in-net).

Answer (score 0):

There is the commercial [Aspose.Pdf library](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) that allows for **[PDF to TIFF conversion](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Convert+Particular+PDF+page+to+TIFF+Image)**.

We are using the products a lot in our products, although I never used the PDF to TIFF conversion. So you better try out whether the results are good enough for your needs.

Of course, if this is no security issue and your PDFs are available public, you could very well simply use the free [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer) to render your documents in the browser, without any plug-in.

Comment: After Conversion Can i View the Same File in Asp.Net ??

Comment: @RickJackson Sure. E.g. you could convert the TIFF to a PNG or a JPEG and put it inside an `<IMG>` tag on your website.

Comment: @RickJackson - What if the PDF is more than 1 page?  What kind of image browsing user interface are you planning?

Comment: I am creating an Commerical Application I have read that Google Docs Viewer is free so in the Future if services stop  i will be in a Problem..

Comment: Yes... I have multiple files in my pdf. Let me explain you my actual requirement I want to show a Tranperant Popup Over the PDF. I am getting browser compatibility issues for tranperancy. Here is my Post Link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666568/setting-transperancy-to-iframe-inside-modal-popup/11825618#11825618 Thats the reason i thought of converting the PDf to TIFF on the fly. Will Any 1 Please Guide me How can i accomplish Transperany over PDF ?

Comment: @RickJackson - Why TIFF?  Why not another image format that browsers natively support, like PNG?

Comment: Ok... Tiff can handle multiple pages right ? but there will be problem for PNG... thats the reason for choosing TIFF :)

Comment: @RickJackson - Yes, TIFF can encapsulate multiple pages in one file.  So can PDF.  Neither can be displayed natively by a browser.  They both would require an external plug-in to view.  So if you are going that route, why not just leave it as PDF?  IF you want the browser to be able to display the images without a plug-in, then you need to pick a different image format.

Answer (score 0):

[imageresizer.net](http://www.imageresizing.net) has a PDF plugin and can convert to TIFF, JPG, PNG, etc. It's also open source.